# English dialect/accent that switches out the letter "p" with a voiceless bilabial trill (ʙ̥)

Tags: dialects, phonetics, accent

Just to clarify the title: not sure if this dialect always switches the "p" out with the "ʙ̥". For example, if the *p* is in the beginning of word, maybe this doesn't happen.

Also, I'm not sure this dialect even exists. I have definitely heard this kind of pronunciation, like with the word *appreciation* being pronounced with a voiceless bilabial trill instead of the voiceless bilabial plosive that standard English uses. However, this may be an ideolectic or even situational (to add more drama perhaps) pronunciation.

So my question is this: does there exist an English dialect/accent that does this?

Comment: Why woulds you think there *might* be such a dialect? According to Wikipedia, this ["voiceless bilabial trill"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_bilabial_trill#:~:text=The%20voiceless%20bilabial%20trill%20is,as%20Par%C3%A1%20Ar%C3%A1ra%20and%20Sercquiais.) **is typologically extremely rare**. So why should it turn up among native Anglophones?

Comment: @FumbleFingers The only reason I think so is that I've heard it multiple times; I believe I've heard it by British speakers with dark skin, but I'm not sure. As I said in the post, I'm open to it being simply an ideolectic or situation pronounciation. It occured to me know that it may even be a sociolectic pronounciation. As for why it would turn up among native Anglophones: first of all, the speakers are not necessarily native, as I did say "dialect/accent". Second of all, I do believe that this pronounciation is, if a trait within a dialect, caused by foreign influences.

Comment: Are you sure that it's the double 'p' that results in the voiceless trill or the three-letter combination 'ppr'? For example does it happen once or twice in the sentence "I'd **appreciate** it if you would be brief, I have an **appointment** at three". Saying that to myself with a trill only on **appreciate** I feel that it could be a Welsh accent you're looking for, particularly South Walsh.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I do believe that it only happens with the "ppr" as you said. I'll look into the South Welsh accent and see if it matches what I've heard.

Comment: @A.Kvåle I thought it might be the case that it was associated with "ppr" rather than "pp". In my opinion the trill is associated with the 'r' rather than the "pp".

Comment: @BoldBen Could you perhaps direct me to any videos containing or audio containing the South Welsh accent? I had some trouble trying to find good samples.